# How to reset tail.select list to default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tail.select

How can I reset select values from tail.select (Link to https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select) using JS or JQuery, I tried changing the value from select, but it doesn't help.

```
       <select class="form-control searchSelect">
            <option value="" selected disabled>&nbsp;</option>
            <option value="1">V1</option>
            <option value="2">V2</option>
            <option value="3">V3</option>
        </select>
        
        <button type="button" class="resetList">Reset List</button>
<script>
  let tselect = tail.select('.searchSelect', {
                        search:true,
                        deselect:true,
                        hideSelected:true,
                        hideDisabled:true
                    });
    
 $(document).on('click', '.resetList', function(){ 
    $('.searchSelect ').val();
    $(".searchSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected"); 
    $('.searchSelect').val(null).trigger('change');
 });

</script>
```

I have tried till

> $('.searchSelect ').val();
>
> $(".searchSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
>
> $('.searchSelect').val(null).trigger('change');

I read the documentation, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal example of this ? so that it can answered  properly!

Comment: Even I have tried to find minimal example in documentation https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select/wiki/Public-Options#deselect

But i couldn't I don't know how use the syntax which they have mentioned in above link

Comment: I would like to note a change for the `tail.select` library. The old repository is gone completely and the new version is here -

https://github.com/wolffe/tail.select.js

Also, the demo is available here -

https://getbutterfly.com/tail-select/

Since the plugin has disappeared, a few months ago, I have updated it to version 0.5.20 and an ES6 version 0.6 is in the works. I am maintaining this plugin/library full time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`reload()`](https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select/wiki/public-methods#reload) method of the `tail.select()` object:

```js
let tselect = tail.select('.searchSelect', {
            search:true,
            deselect:true,
            hideSelected:true,
            hideDisabled:true
        });

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => tselect.reload());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tail.select@latest"></script>

<select class="form-control searchSelect">
    <option value="" selected disabled>&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="1">V1</option>
    <option value="2">V2</option>
    <option value="3">V3</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="resetList">Reset List</button>
```

If you don't want to clear the text that is in the filter input, then use can use the [`query()`](https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select/wiki/public-methods#querysearch-conf) method without arguments:

```js
let tselect = tail.select('.searchSelect', {
            search:true,
            deselect:true,
            hideSelected:true,
            hideDisabled:true
        });

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => tselect.query());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tail.select@latest"></script>

<select class="form-control searchSelect">
    <option value="" selected disabled>&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="1">V1</option>
    <option value="2">V2</option>
    <option value="3">V3</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="resetList">Reset List</button>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: tselect.reload is not a function

Even i have tried 
tail.reload('.searchSelect'); 
but still getting Uncaught TypeError

Comment: Strange, did you use the latest version? As you can see it works without error in this snippet. Did you run it here? Is `tselect` within scope where you call `tselect.reload()`?

Comment: May be you are right i might not using within a scope .
I am trying to use this function when bootstrap modal closes . It has callback function Ill update in quetion.

Comment: *"I might not"*: you can surely check the value of  `tselect`, no?

Comment: Just make sure you attach the click handler right at the same spot where you define `tselect`, ...

Comment: And please do NOT include elements of my answer in your updated question. That just makes my answer look stupid. Instead debug your code, and inspect the value of `tselect`.

Comment: I have console logged tselect variable its showing all array & objects in inside that modal close callback function but if i run tselect.reload() or tselect.query() its showing uncaught error .

Comment: Which version of `tail` are you using? Is it the latest? Can you give the URL from where you load it?

Comment: Evidently your `tselect` object is not what it should be. Can you please create a runnable fiddle that reproduces the issue (like on jsfiddle)? As you can see in my answer, the snippets I have provided work, so there is something else wrong in your code.